# Accessing interactive output of command started in crontab

Tags: shell, cron

I'm running a game server (Minecraft) on Raspberry Pi OS. I want the server to start whenever the device starts so I've added the following line to `crontab`:

```
@reboot user cd /home/user/nukkit && java -jar nukkit.jar
```

(`user` is the user I log in as)

When ran normally this command starts an interactive prompt that I can use to interact with the server. I can run commands, check what people are writing in chat, etc.

When starting it with `crontab` however I can't find a way to access this interactive prompt. I assumed it would be listed under `jobs` if I started it as my user but there's no jobs listed.

Is there any way for me to access the server's prompt? Should I ditch crontab in favor of something else?

Comment: use screen/tmux/zellij

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this following Ipor's comment:

```
# /etc/crontab
@reboot user screen -dmS minecraft_server bash -c "cd /home/user/nukkit && java -jar nukkit.jar"
```

Thank you!